# How not to display ALL items of a database

Tags: database

When I select a category from the head navigation bar in a database http://www.taracomplementos.com/tara/, the default display is all the items of the DB, and you must select one of the categories inside of the page to see related articles. I wish I knew how to have displayed ONLY the items belonging to a specific category. I think that the trick must be in these lines, but I can't figure out how to modify it:

```
        <div class="sort">
        <ul id="portfolio-control">
            <li class="segment-1"><!-- changed All for todo --><a class="active all" data-value="all" href="#"><?php _e('todo', 'ux') ?></a></li>
            <?php wp_list_categories(array('title_li' => '', 'exclude' => $excludecat,'taxonomy' => 'skill-type', 'walker' => new Walker_Category_Filter())); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; else : endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="span16 gallery">
    <?php $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'portfolio',
       'orderby'=>'menu_order',
       'order'     => 'ASC',
       'posts_per_page' => '-1',
       'skill-type' => get_query_var('skill-type'),
       'tax_query' => array(
       array(
               'taxonomy' => 'skill-type',
               'field' => 'id',
               'terms' => $excludecat,
               'operator' => 'NOT IN',
               )
           ) // end of tax_query
       );
    ?>
    <?php $query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
```

Can anybody help me? TIA,
guido

Answer (score 1):

Check if excludecat is containing category IDs or category slugs, if it is using slugs/text then change the ID field to slug.

Also define the relation to use, e.g.:

```
'relation' => 'AND',
```

Here are the parameters: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: I don't get what I should do. Here goes the code:
  <?php
  $excludecat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thb-xclude', false);
  $excludecat = implode(", ",$excludecat);
  ?>

Comment: <?php $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'orderby'=>'menu_order',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'skill-type' => get_query_var('skill-type'),
        'tax_query' => array(
        array(
                'taxonomy' => 'skill-type',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $excludecat,
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                )
            ) // end of tax_query
        );
     ?>

Comment: refer to the taxonomy parameters link for examples on where to put the 'relation' parameter

Comment: No way. The 'relation' parameter doesn't change anything. The problem should not be complex for anybody with some skill of Wordpress and DB. I don't wish to have all the DB items shown when I display a category, but only the items belonging to that main category. Here goes the code, if anybody wishes to have a look: http://pastebin.com/xTS9xaJP. The site is www.taracomplementos.com/tara/

Comment: you MUST define the relation parameter, regardless of whether it fixes your issue, it is expected, and has an impact. Odd I know but its good practice.

Comment: and again, what form does $exclude_cat take. We know its an array, but what of? Term IDs or Term slugs?

Comment: If you don't know could you do something like `print_r($exclude_cat); wp_die('');`  and let us know what gets printed?

Comment: OK, I've defined the relation parameters, adding 'relation' => 'AND' after 'tax_query' => array(
For the rest, I am sorry, but I don't know how to do something like print_r($exclude_cat); wp_die('');. I am not a programmer, just tell me how to do it, and I'll get back with the result. Sorry :-(

Comment: I can give you admin access to the wp, but I guess that you have more interesting things to do... Anyway, if you wish to do that, just tell me guido at twomany.com

Comment: It isn't hard, just before your query, copy the `print_r($exclude_cat); wp_die('');`, paste, save, and open the page, put the output in a pastebin, then link me to it. Then remove that snippet of code afterwards or comment it out.

Comment: also can you post the entire code? I can't see where $exclude_cat is being defined/declared, its just being pulled out of thin air (perhaps this is the cause of your issue)